# Print current time (with milliseconds)

Tags: bash, cygwin, time

I want this command in windows with `cygwin` installed, so any Linux command will work for me.

Comment: how about this: echo $(($(date +%s%N)/1000000))

[Linux command to get time in milliseconds (on stackoverflow)][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16548528/linux-command-to-get-time-in-milliseconds

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`date +%H:%M:%S:%N` will give you the current time with nano seconds, you could then chop off however many digits or rearrange the time to how you wish to have it.

`date --help` can give you some other configuration options

Comment: Maybe it should be noted that on most platforms, you don't get exact nanoseconds. For instance in my case, the last two digits are always zero, from which I conclude that i get at best a resolution of 100ns precision.

Answer (score 43):

If you want to get milliseconds instead of nanoseconds, you may simply use `%3N` to truncate the nanoseconds to the 3 most significant digits:

```
$ date +"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S,%3N"
2014-01-08 16:00:12,746
```

or

```
$ date +"%F %T,%3N"
2014-01-08 16:00:12,746
```

testet with »GNU bash, Version 4.2.25(1)-release (i686-pc-linux-gnu)«

Also tested successfully in my cygwin installation.

But be aware, that %N may not implemented depending on your target system or bash version.
Tested on an embedded system »GNU bash, version 4.2.37(2)-release (arm-buildroot-linux-gnueabi)« there was no `%N`:

```
date +"%F %T,%N"
2014-01-08 16:44:47,%N
```

Comment: Since `date` is not a shell builtin, `date --version` or similar are relevant, not the exact shell version.

Comment: You're right. In this case, it was busybox v1.21.0 (buildroot rootfs, compiled using a non-HF arm cross toolchain). `date --version` gave `unrecognized option` error there.

Comment: 4 years later and I gotta say THANK YOU I just learned that you can truncate from the date command itself. Amazing.

Comment: 2021 - and the %N is not working in WSL.

export PS1="\[\033[33m\]\D{%H:%M:%S.%N}\[\033[00m\] \[\033[32m\]\u@$Ubuntu-20.04\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[36m\]\w\[\033
[00m\]$ "

Gets me:
10:16:25.%N mba@-20.04:/mnt/c/WINDOWS/system32$

Answer (score 2):

Here is the command where you can print the **json-like ISO** format current time:

```sh
date +%FT%T.%3N
```

Answer (score 1):

To be ISO complete I would use either:

```
date +%FT%T.%3N%z
```

for lcal time, or:

```
date -u +%FT%T.%3NZ
```

for UTC.